# What is Teradata Client 14.10

Tags: teradata

In relation to Teradata Client 14.10, I was wondering if I could use this tool to run SQL, view tables and change passwords?

New to teradata.

Many Thanks.

Comment: *Teradata Client* (aka *TTU, Teradata Tools & Utilities*) is not a single tool, it's the full collection of all client tools (load, admin, drivers, etc.), e.g. for Windows: http://downloads.teradata.com/download/tools/teradata-tools-and-utilities-windows-installation-package. You can also use Teradata Studio (Express) for those tasks, check http://downloads.teradata.com/download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the SQL Assistant from the client set, it would suffice.

Studio is too cranky at this point, was supposed to be an equivalent eventually replacing the assistant.

Answer (score 0):

... teradata studio; a pre-baked eclipse plugin. Works pretty well and doesn't require all the old men ODBC configuration '90s msft weirdness. sorry a 'lil high rugh now.